# Experimental design and precision for calculating moment of inertia

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, inertial-frames, error-analysis, experimental-technique

Here is the experiment: A hanging mass is placed on one end of a three-step pulley. The pulley rotates a rod with masses, $m_1$ and $m_2$, on each end.
Now, we know the moment of inertia of the two masses is: $I = (m_1 + m_2)R^{2}$, where $R$ is the distance between the mass and the axis of rotation.

My question is should we increase $R$ or decrease $R$ for more precision? I'm thinking that if we increase $R$ any slight deviation will scale exponentially and lead to less accurate results.

Answer (score 1):

You want to calculate the uncertainty $\Delta I$ in $I(R)$ given an uncertainty $\Delta R$ in $R$. That is called error propagation. The formula is

$\Delta I = \frac{\partial I(R)}{\partial R}\Delta R = 2(m_1+m_2)R \Delta R$

hence your relative error goes like

$\frac{\Delta I}{I}\propto\frac{1}{R}$.

Thus, for given precision $\Delta R$, an increased radius gives a better result.